# Logback not accepting Html tags

Tags: html, logback

I am using Logback for logging in my application. I am using HTMLLayout and my msg is formatted already but when logbak print that msg its not showing formatted msg.

My code in logback is :

```
    <appender name="INFO-HTML"
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}%level%msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
    <file>${TOMCAT_ROOT}/infolog.html</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FOLDER}/archived/infolog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1MB</totalSizeCap>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

message example:

HTTP REQUEST :  User: unknown - Path: resorts - Header: {host=[localhost:8022], connection=[keep-alive], content-length=[795], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36], cache-control=[no-cache], origin=[chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop], content-type=[application/json], authorization=[g8mm505be952dc27b7hofgaa0la1], postman-token=[21c3aba1-9629-9352-7d6b-25c2dcbc3eaf], accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], accept-language=[pt], authToken=[g8mm505be952dc27b7hofgaa0la1]} - 
Entity: { "url": "sdfbgs",
    "videos": null,
    "serviceIds": null,
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "isPublished": false } 

I have removed few key-value pairs from json which may create confusion to understand. And I have added start of html tag after 'HTTP REQUEST :' and end of that tag is placed at end of message.

Comment: In your question you state "my msg is formatted already", could you update the question to include an **example** of the message you are attempting to log?

Comment: I have updated question with example.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my Own question.

I completed it using Java class HTMLLayout which extends HTMLLayout class in logback library.

Then given that class path in logback.xml file.

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/xhh/284628) to create HTMLLayout class. More precisely, At line 61, in provided link, that pre tag is used solved my issue.